# How do I get a "Style" menu in my Haddock documentation?

Tags: css, haskell, haddock

Some packages (the Haddock documentation for example [Data.String.Utils](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hS3-0.5.8/docs/Data-String-Utils.html)) have a menubar that includes a "Style" menu that allows choosing among styles used to display the documentation:

[image]

How do I get this menu in the documentation for my own packages? What setting should I use to include it, and how do I specify which styles are offered?

I've tried things like

```
haddock
  -- ...
  css: /path/to/mystuff.css, Default, Ocean
  -- ...
```

and

```
haddock

  -- ...
  css: Default
  css: Ocean
  css: /path/to/mystuff.css
  -- ...
```

In my `~/.cabal/config`; but the former fails and the latter just formats using the last-listed `css` entry, with no "Style" menu.

Comment: Try "theme"? https://haskell-haddock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/invoking.html#cmdoption-theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is implemented with the `--theme` flag to Haddock: https://haskell-haddock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/invoking.html#cmdoption-theme

Comment: That seems to do the trick locally, but how do I enforce that on [Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/crypto-enigma-0.1.1.6/docs/Crypto-Enigma.html) and [Stackage](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-16.15/crypto-enigma-0.1.1.6/Crypto-Enigma.html)? I don't see where I can specify `--theme` for either.